# Retirar o focus/outline do input (CSS)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, react

Como retiro esse focus/outline do input?

Esse é o meu HTML

Estou usando ReactJS, Bootstrap-react

```
<div className="viewInstrument-table-heading">
                    <div className="table-heading1">
                        <span>Parâmetros</span>                      
                        <i className="material-icons flip">assignment_return</i>
                        <i className="material-icons">cached</i>                            
                    </div>

                    <div className="table-heading2">
                         <FormGroup className="viewInstrument-formSearch">                            
                            <InputGroup>
                                <InputGroup.Addon>
                                    <i className="material-icons icon-search">search</i>
                                </InputGroup.Addon>
                                <FormControl placeholder="Pesquisar instrumento" type="text" />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Ele fica assim quando clico dentro do input:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já testaste com CSS `input:focus{
    outline: none;
}`?

Comment: Já tentei, mas não deu certo!

Comment: Podes criar um jsFiddle?

Comment: Vou criar um...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

É so fazer assim no CSS
Tudo isso vira HTML, então funcionara, se preferir, voce também pode add uma className direto do FormControl

```
    handleFocus: function(event) {
  event.target.select();
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <input type='text' value='Some something' onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
  );
},
```

Comment: Não funciona...#search{
                        outline: none;
                    }

Comment: Ele continua com o focus...

Comment: tentou colocar um !important?  input{outline: none !important}

Comment: Coloquei tbm com !important... mas não tira... não sei se é pq estou usando o bootstrap.

Comment: Tenta isso

handleFocus: function(event) {
  event.target.select();
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <input type='text' value='Some something' onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
  );
},

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Olha, pelo que já responderam pra ti e pelo que vejo na imagem que tu mandou, isso não é um `outline`, e sim um `box-shadow`, ou talvez até uma borda com opacidade diferenciada. Coloca um `border: none`, e também um `box-shadow: none` no seu elemento.

Em situações como essa, roda a página, clica com o botão direito no elemento, vai em "Inspecionar Elemento" (talvez tenha que fazer isso 2x, porque o primeiro inspecionar elemento pega no body normalmente), e olha as classes/CSS dele na direita. Ali você deve encontrar o que tá causando essa borda/outline do elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

declare uma classe css em seu elemento. Ex: `<button class="button"></button>`
daclare uma classe css com a popriedade outline:none :

`.button{
   outline: 0;
}`

Ao clicar no button, não aparecerá mais as linhas de focus.

Answer (score -3):

Bota a propriedade **outline** como *none*. Em css normal ficaria:

```
input:focus{
outline: none;
}
```